# Memory Free using SUN RPC

Tags: c, memory-management, rpc

all. When I use 
`static char* result = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));`
in one procedure of the server program based on ONC+ SUN RPC. But this string is the what should be returned.

If it is static, I think there is no need to free it. For every time, string result will be allocated the same address, not cause memory conflicts.

Am I right? Or what should I do? This is the return value, how to free it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are using the initializer in a function call that returns type `char*`.  In that case, there is no problem with using the static storage class.  `result` will keep its value (the memory address you allocated) throughout the life of your program.

However, malloc will not be called multiple times in this instance.  Only the first time through your function.  Also, the memory is still allocated on the heap, thus you still need to free it when you are done.  However, this freeing will be performed on your program's exit(), so that could be ignored.

Comment: Although you are right that the memory will be automatically reclaimed by the operating system at the end of your application, this is never an argument for begin 'lazy' regarding memory management.  If you allocate memory, always free it somewhere later in your application, even if it means that this is at exit.